# How do I make a series of colorful Rectangles using noise?

Tags: opengl, glsl, rectangles, fragment-shader, noise

I am currently learning about generating Noise patterns in GLSL.

I am trying to create a composition of rectangles, colors and noise using a fragment shader in GLSL. Here is my current code:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;

// 2D Random
float random (in vec2 st) {
    return fract(sin(dot(st.xy,
                     vec2(12.9898, 79)))
             * 43758.5453123);
}

float noise (in vec2 st) 
{
    vec2 i = floor(st + 1.0);
    vec2 f = fract(st);

    // Four corners in 2D of a tile
    float a = random(i);
    float b = random(i + vec2(1.0, 0.0));
    float c = random(i + vec2(0.0, 1.0));
    float d = random(i + vec2(1.0, 1.0));

    vec2 u = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    u = smoothstep(0.6, 1.0, f);

    // Mix 4 coorners percentages
    return mix(a, b, u.x) +
        (c - a)* u.y * (1.0 - u.x) +
        (d - b) * u.x * u.y;
}

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;

    vec3 color = vec3(0.423,0.459,1.000);

    vec2 pos = vec2(st * 4.0);

    // Use the noise function
    float n = noise(pos);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(n), color);
}
```

Currently all I can get it to generate are black and white squares and rectangles and no matter how I adjust my "vec3 color" variable I can't get it show the rectangles in various colors.

My question is: how can I adjust my code so that it breaks down into just a handful of rectangles instead of squares and rectangles and how can I make my color apply to those rectangles?? This is all still foreign to me so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"how can I adjust my code so that it breaks down into just a handful of rectangles instead of squares and rectangles"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I make my color apply to those rectangles

You have to multiply `color` by the gradient `n`:

```c
gl_FragColor = vec4(color * n, 1.0);
```

---

The misalignment of the rectangles is related to the line

> ```c
> u = smoothstep(0.6, 1.0, f)
> ```

You have to shift the rectangles dependent on the size of the smooth area:

```c
float noise (in vec2 st) 
{
    float smoothsize = 0.2;  
    st -= smoothsize;
    vec2 i = floor(st + 1.0);
    vec2 f = fract(st);

    // [...]

    vec2 u = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    u = smoothstep(1.0- 2.0*smoothsize, 1.0, f);
    
    // [...]
}
```

---

If you want to generate squares instead of rectangles, then you have to scale the `st.x` by the aspect ratio:

```c
vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
st.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;
```

---

Complete fragment shader:

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;

// 2D Random
float random (in vec2 st)
{
    return fract(sin(dot(st.xy, vec2(12.9898, 79))) * 43758.5453123);
}

float noise (in vec2 st) 
{
    float smoothsize = 0.2;
    st -= smoothsize;
    vec2 i = floor(st + 1.0);
    vec2 f = fract(st);

    // Four corners in 2D of a tile
    float a = random(i);
    float b = random(i + vec2(1.0, 0.0));
    float c = random(i + vec2(0.0, 1.0));
    float d = random(i + vec2(1.0, 1.0));

    vec2 u = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    u = smoothstep(1.0- 2.0*smoothsize, 1.0, f);

    // Mix 4 corners percentages
    return mix(a, b, u.x) + (c-a) * u.y * (1.0-u.x) + (d-b) * u.x * u.y;
}

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
    // st.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y; <--- optional

    // Use the noise function
    float n = noise(st * 4.0);

    vec3 color = vec3(0.423,0.459,1.000);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color * n, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps a lot. :)

Comment: Lets say I wanted to use multiple colors. Do I simply just add more color variables to the main() function and mix them with the gradient?

Comment: @Garrus Do you want to use fixed or random colors?

Comment: Fixed colors. I don't want to shift or change.

Comment: @Garrus `gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(color, color2, n), 1.0);` - gradient between 2 colors

Comment: Would this work if I wanted certain rectangles to be different colors? Like have the ones on the left be red, the middle be blue, and the ones on the right be yellow?